# Select remote database from bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, shell-scripting

I'm kind of new in bash/shell scripting and I'm trying to remotely select from mysql database and check if record exist or no. Based on respond will do some stuff.

This is what I have as a command

```
mysql -u mysql -pMysql123 -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx MYDBNAME -e "select count(column) from TABLE where column=1234;"
```

When I run this command directly in terminal I've got correct response. So I'm trying to put it in the script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

count=mysql -u mysql -pMysql123 -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx MYDBNAME -e "select count(column) from TABLE where column=1234;"

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
     echo " greater that 0 "
else
     echo " lower than 0 "
fi
```

When I execute above script the output is

> $ ./check.sh
>
> ./check.sh: line 3: -u: command not found
>
> ./check.sh: line 5: [: -gt: unary operator expected
>
> lower than 0

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need a subshell. try this:

```
count=$(mysql -u mysql -pMysql123 -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx MYDBNAME -sse "select count(column) from TABLE where column=1234;")

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
     echo " greater that 0 "
else
     echo " lower than 0 "
fi
```

also take note of the `-s` option:

```
--silent, -s
Silent mode. Produce less output. This option can be given multiple times to produce less and less output.
```

Comment: Actually now I got this error: `./check.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments` because `$count` return `count(column) 1` when I echoed it

Comment: So the question is how to just check if exist or no.. must return only 1/0 not whole name like `count(column) 1`

Comment: I fixed my answer, I tested it this time and it works. Please try that